# Analyticity of the regularized $\eta$-invariant

Tags: analytic-number-theory, differential-topology, differential-operators, index-theory

The APS $\eta$- invariant of an operator $B$ with eigenvalues $\lambda$ is defined as
$$\eta = \sum_\lambda sgn (\lambda)$$
which is a divergent sum and it can be regularized as follows:
$$\eta(s) = \sum_\lambda \frac{sgn (\lambda)}{|\lambda|^s} $$
This function has a pole at $s = 0$ but for certain type of operators $B$, the residue at $s = 0$ vanishes and hence it is analytic at $s =0$. I came across another regularization of $\eta$ invariant
$$\eta (\beta) = \sum_\lambda sgn(\lambda) Erfc(|\lambda|\sqrt{\beta})$$
where Erfc is the complimentary error function. Is it possible to show that $\eta(\beta)$ is also analytic at $\beta = 0$ and both these limits i.e. $s\rightarrow 0$ and $\beta \rightarrow 0$ match?